# How to customize the text color of navigationbar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, uinavigationbar

I am trying to change the color of the text that is the title of the navigationbar in UINavigation bar's drawRectangle and it hasn't worked so far. I am also wondering if it is possible to change the height of the bar in any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could add a UILabel with the color you want and add it to the navigationbar instead of using the default title field.

titleView
A custom view displayed in the center of the navigation bar when this item is the top item.

> @property(nonatomic, retain) UIView
>   *titleView Discussion If this property value is nil, the navigation item’s
>   title is displayed in the center of
>   the navigation bar when this item is
>   the top item. If you set this property
>   to a custom title, it is displayed
>   instead of the title. This property is
>   ignored if leftBarButtonItem is not
>   nil.
>
> Custom views can contain buttons. Use
>   the buttonWithType: method in UIButton
>   class to add buttons to your custom
>   view in the style of the navigation
>   bar. Custom title views are centered
>   on the navigation bar and may be
>   resized to fit.
>
> The default value is nil.
>
> Availability Available in iOS 2.0 and
>   later. Declared In UINavigationBar.h

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#DOCUMENTATION/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationItem_Class/Reference/UINavigationItem.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006933

Comment: @Jackelope11: I updated my post. You just make a new UILabel object, then you customize in the way you font (setting color, size etc.) then you use self.navigationItem.titleView = yourLabelReference; (Not on Mac right now, but I think this is correct syntax!)